# How to check if an element in one vector is present in the second vector after a condition is satisfied?

Tags: r, functional-programming, conditional-statements

I have two vectors namely `d1` and `d2`.

```
d1 <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Lion", "Tiger", "Horse")
d2 <- c("Tiger", "Rat", "Lion", "Horse","Dog")
```

I wish to check if the vector in the first position of `d1` matches with the fifth position of `d2`. Similarly check if second position in vector `d1` matches with fourth position of vector `d2` and so on.
There are three possible outcomes:-

a) The vector in `d1` is present in the vector `d2` and the positions also match.

b) The vector in `d1` is present in the vector `d2`. But the positions do not match.

c) The vector in `d1` is not contained in `d2`.

The expected output is as follows:-

```
 Dog is present in the second vector and the positions match.
 Cat is not present in the second vector.
 Lion is present in the second vector and the positions match.
 Tiger is present in the second vector. But the positions do not match.
 Horse is present in the second vector. But the positions do not match.
```

Comment: `d1 == rev(d2)` and `d1 %in% d2` let you test this.

Comment: @Roland d1 == rev(d2) returns only True or False values. Is there any way I could incorporate this in the code and achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach with a function and dataframes and using the helpful comments of @Roland:

```
d1 <- c("Dog", "Cat", "Lion", "Tiger", "Horse")
d2 <- c("Tiger", "Rat", "Lion", "Horse","Dog")

check_function <- function(x,y)
{
  df <- data.frame(v1=x,v2=rev(y),stringsAsFactors = F)
  df$i1 <- df$v1 %in% df$v2
  df$i2 <- df$v1==df$v2
  #Create messages
  df$Message <- ifelse(df$i1==T & df$i2==T,paste0(df$v1,' is present in second vector and match'),
                       ifelse(df$i1==T & df$i2==F,paste0(df$v1,' is present in second vector but no match'),
                              paste0(df$v1,' is not present in second vector')))
  return(df$Message)
}

check_function(d1,d2)

[1] "Dog is present in second vector and match"      "Cat is not present in second vector"           
[3] "Lion is present in second vector and match"     "Tiger is present in second vector but no match"
[5] "Horse is present in second vector but no match"
```

Comment: Need to ask some general things about R? Could you please share your Linkedin Username?

Comment: @Silent_bliss Yeah of course. Better could you give me an email so that we can chat?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/218657/r-sharing-and-learning?tab=general